# Add pluralization option to impact block related strings

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, localization, plurals

Currently there are no strings depend on count in impact block of user [profile page activity tab](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176217/%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B5%CF%87%CE%BF%CE%BB%CF%85%CF%84?tab=topactivity):

> [image: Impact block]

Each item has only one sentence to translate:

- [people reached](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/8934)
- [posts edited](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17310)
- <s>[helpful flags](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17243)</s> // pluralized: [one](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18064), [few](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18062), [many](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/18063)
- [votes cast](https://ru.traducir.win/strings/17300)

Adding pluralizable strings will be appreciated for localized Stack Exchange sites.