# Pluralization issues in the Impact summary

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, plurals

In the Impact summary (in the Summary tab under profile page), there are three pluralization issues:

- 1 post**s** edited
- 1 helpful flag**s** (Already reported here: [Pluralization issue in "helpful flags" text in profile activity summary page, when there is only one helpful flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375905/pluralization-issue-in-helpful-flags-text-in-profile-activity-summary-page-wh))
- 1 vote**s** cast

They should read as:

- 1 post edited
- 1 helpful flag
- 1 vote cast

Screenshot for reference:

[image]

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/374964/add-pluralization-option-to-impact-block-related-strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, looks like these strings weren't pluralized. Should be fixed now.

Thanks for the report! Here's an **S Friend**:

[image: S Friend]

Comment: Is the S Friend new? Don't remember seeing them before. ;)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard, new(ish) - Just my own pet projet when closing pluralization tickets - also seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377666/209031) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/377661/209031).  Kind of my anti blugeon-you-with-an-S sorta thing.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be fixed (specifically) on Stack Overflow, at least for the ["votes cast" text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INN5U.png) (I couldn't readily find instances of "1 helpful flags" and "1 posts edited"). It seems to be fixed elsewhere ([example](https://askubuntu.com/users/1595153/justin)).

Comment: Thanks Justin - I'll take another poke and figure out what's going on

Comment: Thankfully, [Jeff Atwood's meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) no longer applies, in fact quite the opposite. Is there a place where it is positively stated, e.g. in the *[Stacks](https://stackoverflow.design/)* [design system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_system)?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum, where what is positively stated?  That we want to handle pluralization correctly?  We could probably add it to our [content principals](https://stackoverflow.design/content/guidelines/principles/)